# How would I solve a "Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task<string>'to 'string'" error in this example?

Tags: c#, wpf, asynchronous, async-await, command-line-interface

I have been experimenting with async and Cli wrap to try and make a network scanner. It involves taking data from a powershell command, storing it in an object and then displaying it in a WPF gui. But every time i try to construct it i get this error.

I have messed around with it trying to not run it asynchronusly but have found no possible way what with Cli wrap. I have also tried adding await to parts of it but that has just caused more errors as you would expect. Any help would be much appreciated, thank you. Here is my code so far:

```
        //method to return ARP data
        static async Task<string> ArpData()
        {
            var powerShellResults = await Cli.Wrap("powershell")
                .WithArguments("arp -a")
                .ExecuteBufferedAsync();
            return powerShellResults.StandardOutput;
        }
        //time of snapshot, to be given when taken
        public int time;
        public string data = ArpData();
        
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
```

Comment: In your constructor, you can do  `data = await ArpData();`, but StandardOutput of powershell returns a StreamReader, not a string.

Comment: To perhaps clarify. It is await that will wait for the string to return  out of the task. Otherwise it's a task<string>.  I think that's the cliwrap nuget package being used. In which case standard output is a string.

Comment: You can not use await in a constructor. Move the call to an async Loaded event handler.

Comment: thank you very much all of you i have got it working now